# python 3.5 - PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied in visual studio 2015

Tags: python, visual-studio

In my code, I am trying to open a file using append, to check if the file exists or not and what is inside.

```
def setFile():

# Create file if it does not exist
openingFile = open('talents.txt', 'a')
openingFile.close()

# Read file
openingFile = open('talents.txt', 'r')
read = openingFile.read()

# Check for nothing
if read == '':
    openingFile.close()
    openingFile = open('talents.txt', 'w')
    openingFile.write("100")

# Check for 0
if read == '0':
    openingFile.close()
    openingFile = open('talents.txt', 'w')
    openingFile.write("100")
```

It runs perfectly fine when I run it in cmd and on my linux machine, but in Visual Studio 2015 it throws a permission denied when trying to open the file in append. How do I fix this?

P.S. I would really like to not use r+